# How to disable the link "switch to Desktop version" in mobile version of Joomla 2.5?

Tags: php, html, css, responsive-design, joomla2.5

I want my desktop version to be the default view.

I want to disable the "switch to Desktop version" link when the user views the site with phone or tablet.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Edited a subject line a bit but needs improvement on the description by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely an option that can be enabled or disabled in the Joomla template.

Template options can be changed in Joomla 2.5 by logging in to the back-end and going to Extensions -> Template Manager and editing the default Site template.